# Jquery plugin: backstretch not working as it should

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an html page, I would like to put a background image inside the body element that fit and stretch as the windows resize.
I use backstretch plugin but it only show the top part of the image and not the bottom. I don't know how fix this problem.
Here the html page and then the css file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My Page</title>

<link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backstretch.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.backstretch("img/bg.jpg");
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here the very simple css file:

```
body{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

the path is correct as it show the image even if it is only a part, the top part, not the bottom (footer) [image: background image i want to use]

Comment: You don't need a plugin to achieve a full background image. It can be done entirely through CSS - see link https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: thanks! very usefull :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backstretch will always try to keep the aspect ratio of the image, so for some window sizes you are not seeing the bottom of the image.

It can be accomplished with CSS only, this might not be exactly what you need, it works with the provided image because it can repeat in the x axis:

```
html { 
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/10zrl.jpg) repeat-x center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not work if you do not want to repeat any axis. It does not keep the proper scale.